# jCrop on resized images

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jcrop

I am setting `max-width` css property for images to display on the page.
however this breaks the jCrop. On the left is what i selected. On the right is what is cropped after I crop it. I have used this example here.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET

[image: This is what i select]
[image: This is what is actually cropped]

thanks for help.

Comment: @SatpalSingh i thought it was as clear as it gets. you can see on the left image the area i am selecting to crop. however the cropped image turns out to be the one on the right.

Comment: To make this work you need to remap the position of the thumbnail image to the new size of the big image. With max-width probably the change of the size image need to recalculate somehow, maybe is better to set the width from the start to some size and not let it auto.

Comment: return Imaged to be cropped in fixed dimension, that what i did

Comment: @SatpalSingh i am using the exact code in that link. and only setting css for the img to be cropped as `{max-width:800px}`

Comment: @btevfik: Aristos is right

Comment: @Matías i ended up resizing the image itself to 800px before allowing user to crop.

Answer (score 2):

The jcrop is working well with fixed max-width. I have also test that one.
May be possible you are cropping the wrong area as shown right square.

Answer (score 0):

you can confige Jcrop with a maximum width and height

```
$( "#cropsource" ).Jcrop({ boxWidth: 800, boxHeight: 500 });
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a workaround to this?